# Jquery calculate sum with program start

Tags: jquery, sum

i have calculation with jquery and html. it doesn't calculates on web page load, and does when i insert some value into `<input>`. what can i do to calculate `<input>` value with page load? please help i need it today plzz.

and here is js fiddle [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laicekid/3DB6r/15/)

HTML

```
    <table border="1" class="sumtable">

    <tr>
        <td>Amount 1</td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Amount 2</td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Amount 3</td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Total Amount</td>
        <td><span class="total">0</span></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){           
        $('input').each(function() {
            $(this).keyup(function(){  
                calculateTotal($(this));
            });
        });
    });

    function calculateTotal(src) {
        var sum = 0;
        var sumtable = src.closest('.sumtable');

        sumtable.find('input').each(function() {
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });

        sumtable.find(".total").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `trigger()` to trigger events:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function(){  
        calculateTotal($(this));
    });
    $(this).trigger('keyup');
});
```